# Bulk import to AD powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting

I'm trying to import en employee list into AD using powershell.
The script needs to update exisisting AD objects.

The problem I have is that some users will have mobile number some internal numbers and some just an extension, when i run the Set-ADuser command in its most basic form it seems to fail whenever a value is blank.

I'm not great at scripting, can anyone explain to me why the script below doesnt work? And if so could anyone suggest how to make it work? Cheers

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory

$CSVPath = "c:\scripts\ictdepartment2.csv" 
$csvData = Import-CSV $CSVPath -delimiter "," -Header ("SamaccountName","identity","Title","Company","Department","Description","Office","OfficePhone","IPPhone","MobilePhone") 


##

foreach ($line in $csvData) 
{
$accountTable = @{ 
'SamaccountName'= $line.SamaccountName 
'identity'= $line.identity
'title'= $line.title 
'company'= $line.company 
'department'= $line.department 
'description'= $line.description 
'office'= $line.office
'officephone'= $line.officephone 
'IPPhone'= $line.ipPhone 
'mobilephone'= $line.mobilephone 
}
}

##

ForEach($line in $csvData) 
{
$SamaccountName = $line.SamaccountName
$identity = $line.identity
$title = $line.title 
$company = $line.company 
$department = $line.department 
$description = $line.description 
$office = $line.office
$officephone = $line.officephone
$IPPhone = $line.ipPhone 
$mobilephone = $line.mobilephone 
}

##

ForEach($line in $csvData) 
{
if ($officephone -ne $null)
{Set-ADUser -Identity $SamaccountName -OfficePhone $officephone}
if ($mobilephone -ne $null)
{Set-ADUser -Identity $SamaccountName -MobilePhone $mobilephone}
if ($ipphone -ne $null)
{Set-ADUser -Identity $SamaccountName -replace @{ipPhone=$ipphone}}

Set-ADUser -Identity $SamaccountName -Company $Company -Department $Department -Description $Description -Office $office -Title $title
}
```

If i use the following commands it works, however as soon as i add the if $null statement in it again fails :(

```
ForEach($line in $csvData) 
{ 
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($line.samaccountname)'" |
Set-ADUser -Replace @{ipphone=$ipphone}
}

ForEach($line in $csvData) 
{ 
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($line.samaccountname)'" |
Set-ADUser -Company $Company -Department $Department -Description $Description -MobilePhone $mobilephone -Office $office -OfficePhone $officephone -Title $title
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$null` and an empty string ("") are two different data types to powershell.  Replace any instance of `$null` with `""` and you should be good.  Almost all MS provided cmdlets are set to `[ValidateNotNull]`.

I'd like to expand a bit on what `$Null` is.  Powershell is an OOP (Object Oriented Programming) shell with direct hooks into .Net.  `$Null` is a placeholder and an object in it's own right that represents nothing.  Don't worry about fully understanding `$Null` at this point, a lot of people (even some programmers) don't understand `$Null` to the Nth degree.

So why is this relevant now?  Let me link you to [THIS REFERENCE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) but I'll copy the relevant info here...

> ...you cannot use $null to mean "no parameter value." A parameter
>   value of $null overrides the default parameter value.

In your case you're trying to equate one variable's contents to the `$Null` object, it'll never match because only `$Null` is -eq to `$Null`.

An empty string ("") is a `String` object without a value.  Which is why you want to use it with comparison operators (-eq, -lt, -ge) to evaluate other strings.

Comment: Great reply thanks, a lot easier when you know what your trying to do is fundamentally wrong